# Sprite Kit draw method like Cocos2d

Tags: sprite-kit

Is there a sprite kit way to do the Cocos2d draw method?

```
-(void)draw
{
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 255, 255, 255);
    ccDrawCircle(mySprite.position, attackRange, 360, 30, false);
    [super draw];
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There's no custom OpenGL drawing in Sprite Kit (as of iOS 7.1).

While you can draw circles and other shapes using SKShapeNode, they are meant primarily for debugging purposes (analog to the ccDraw functions in cocos2d). The main problem being that shape nodes are not drawn in batches (inefficiently), unlike sprites.